# Visual Studio Error: The "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage" package did not load correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I tried to open a solution in visual studio and got the following error message:
"The "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage" package did not load correctly". It also tells me to look into the log file... here are the (hopefully) relevant error entries from the log file (activity montior log):

```
194 ERROR Type provided must be an Enum. Parameter name: enumType
          C:\Users\uhofstetter\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.cache   Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting.VsShellComponentModelHost 2015/11/25 17:48:41.548 
195 ERROR An error occured while loading assembly cache from the cache file:
          C:\Users\uhofstetter\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.cache   Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting.VsShellComponentModelHost 2015/11/25 17:48:41.549 
196 ERROR Type provided must be an Enum. Parameter name: enumType
          C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\EDITOR\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.dll   Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting.VsShellComponentModelHost 2015/11/25 17:48:41.552 
197 Warning Temporary turn off caching for this assembly for the current session of the application
          C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\EDITOR\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.dll   Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting.VsShellComponentModelHost 2015/11/25 17:48:41.553 

...

235 ERROR SetSite failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage] {E269B994-EF71-4CE0-8BCD-581C217372E8} 80131500 VisualStudio 2015/11/25 17:49:20.531 
236 ERROR End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage] {E269B994-EF71-4CE0-8BCD-581C217372E8} 80131500 VisualStudio 2015/11/25 17:49:20.551
```

does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Btw: I am using Visual Studio Professional 2012

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Have you tried to remove %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache and restarting VS2012 / VS2013 may fix the problem

Comment: how to remove this file? i cannot find this file

Comment: ComponentModelCache is the name of a folder. If you want to keep the old cache, just in case, rename the folder to something like ComponentModelCache_BAD. When Visual Studio restarts it will recreate the ComponentModelCache folder and the editor error should go away.

Comment: It does not work for me. I delete ComponentModelCache folder but not solve my problem.

Comment: Worked with VS2017 just by using a different version number in the folder path.

Comment: Confirmed, this also worked on VS2019, with matching version number of course.

Comment: Worked with VS 2012, with SSIS Project. Can't beleive i had to did this !

Answer (score 14):

With VS2019 I had to:

1. Remove all contents of `C:\Users\{your_username}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\*`
2. Remove `C:\Users\{your_username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxx\ComponentModelCache`
3. Restart Visual Studio as **Admin**, otherwise the folders weren't being recreated/repaired by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

I had that problem with **Visual Studio 2022**, and **starting** the app with **administrator rights** helped. I didn't need to delete the folder mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

the solutions that worked for everyone else

Which seems to be either deleting the folders at both:

```
C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\version_number
// use the following to get to the proper directory for your user name 
// - much easier using windows special folders
%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio
```

and

```
C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\version_number
```

or deleting/renaming

```
C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\version_number\ComponentModelCache   ...
```

Was not enough for me. I had a error which popped up on attempting to load Python projects "0x80070570: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable". If you have this issue running a disk check/repair and reboot followed by the above steps should work.

Comment: Thanks, In my case (running Visual Studio 2013) I only needed to delete the ComponentModelCache directory and everything started working again.